# How to update ManytoManyField in UserChangeForm in Django?

Tags: python, django, manytomanyfield

I want to update user info with **UserChangeForm** and things go pretty well except for the ManyToManyField. When I render the page I can see that all user informations are displayed in correct order of each field like user's username will be in the **username** field but it's blank in manytomanyfield.

```
#model.py
class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('Email Address'), unique=True)
    department = models.ManyToManyField(Department)
    # some other fields

# forms.py
class EditUserForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['email', 'department', ..]
        widgets = {'department': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()}

# view.py
def home(request):
    template_name = "app/home.html"
    edit_form = EditUserForm(instance=request.user)
       if request.method == "POST":
           edit_form = EditUserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
           if edit_form.is_valid():
               edit_form.save()
               return JsonResponse({'success': True}, status=200)
           else:
               return JsonResponse({'error': edit_form.errors}, status=400)
    return render(request, template_name, {'edit_form': edit_form})

# template
              <form action="{% url 'home' %}" method="POST">
                <div class="row">
                  {{edit_form.email}}

                  {{edit_form.first_name}}

                  {% for department in edit_form.department %}
                   <h6 id="checkbox">{{department.tag}} {{department.choice_label}}</h6>
                  {% endfor %}
                </div>
              </form>
```

here is the picture
[image]

As you can see the names and email are displaying inside the form field but why all checkboxes are empty? (Checkbox fields are department)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to render the field you don't need a for loop. You can just use `{{edit_form.department}}`. In case you need to modify each `input` field in `CheckboxSelectMultiple` you should loop through `edit_form.department.field.choices`.
For example:

```
{% for choice, value in edit_form.department.field.choices %}
<input type="checkbox" name="{{choice.instance.value}}" value="{{choice.instance.pk}}" id="id_{{choice.instance.value}}">
{% endfor %}
```

Note that this will work only in django 3.0 and newer.

Comment: I wrote like you wrote and i can see checkboxes and values were rendered out but checkboxes are all empty. it supposed to show what i have checked when i create the object. Are there any option?

Comment: @kimhongMuong What exactly did you try? First or second option? From the picture you provided I can see that you do not apply any special styling to these elements, hence you should be all good with a standard `{{ edit_form.department }}`. Anyway, could you tell what version of Django you use and have you checked if the data from form is correctly recorded in database?

Answer (score 0):

you need pass the value and the name in the input in your template

```
{% for value, name in edit_form.fields.department.choices %}
    <input type="checkbox" name="{{name}}" value="{{value}}" id="{{name}}">
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I wrote like you wrote and i can see checkboxes and values were rendered out but checkboxes are all empty. it supposed to show what i have checked when i create the object. Are there any option?

Comment: you mean no labels there?